# Streamlit app aborts when attempting to execute map reprojection for the second time

Tags: python-3.x, gis, geospatial, streamlit, rasterio

### A simple streamlit app was made for matching the resolution and projection of two raster layers. The app could be executed by clicking on the *Run* button for the first time, but it would be aborted when clicking on the second time.

#### Any suggestion? Thank you very much!

Sample TIFF files:

- [img1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zN5gw2JDaZH0xz4JWPyJeJFinYFXo2lY/view?usp=sharing)
- [img2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1scLxv4g6mPRFlukQBJRt9qsFA5cPCJTF/view?usp=sharing)

##### Here's the code:

```
import os
import sys
import gc
import rioxarray as rxr
import streamlit as st
from rasterio.io import MemoryFile

@st.cache_data
def read_memory(memoryfile):
    with MemoryFile(memoryfile) as mf:
        with mf.open() as ds:
            data_array = rxr.open_rasterio(ds)
    return data_array.squeeze()

uploaded_files = st.file_uploader("TIF files", type=['tif'], accept_multiple_files=True)

if len(uploaded_files) > 0:

    filenames = [file.name for file in uploaded_files]

    img1_filename = st.selectbox("img1: ", options=filenames)
    img2_filename = st.selectbox("img2: ", options=filenames)

    img1_ind = filenames.index(img1_filename)
    img2_ind = filenames.index(img2_filename)

    img1 = read_memory(uploaded_files[img1_ind])
    img2 = read_memory(uploaded_files[img2_ind])
    
    collected_img = [i for i in ['img1', 'img2'] if i in globals()]
    st.code(collected_img)

    if img1 is not None and img2 is not None:

        if st.button("Run"):
            img3 = img1.rio.reproject_match(img2)

            st.code(f"img1: {img1.shape}, {img1.rio.crs}")
            st.code(f"img2: {img2.shape}, {img2.rio.crs}")
            st.code(f"img3: {img3.shape}, {img3.rio.crs}")

    gc.collect()

# streamlit run pycode\test.py
```

##### Here's the error messages:

```
RasterioIOError: No such file or directory
Traceback:
File "D:\pyenv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 552, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "D:\pycode\test.py", line 36, in <module>
    img3 = img1.rio.reproject_match(img2)
File "D:\pyenv\lib\site-packages\rioxarray\raster_array.py", line 546, in reproject_match
    reprojected_data_array = self.reproject(
File "D:\pyenv\lib\site-packages\rioxarray\raster_array.py", line 451, in reproject
    source=self._obj.values,
File "D:\pyenv\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\dataarray.py", line 733, in values
    return self.variable.values
File "D:\pyenv\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\variable.py", line 614, in values
    return _as_array_or_item(self._data)
File "D:\pyenv\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\variable.py", line 314, in _as_array_or_item
    data = np.asarray(data)
File "D:\pyenv\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py", line 693, in __array__
    return np.asarray(self.get_duck_array(), dtype=dtype)
File "D:\pyenv\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py", line 696, in get_duck_array
    self._ensure_cached()
File "D:\pyenv\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py", line 690, in _ensure_cached
    self.array = as_indexable(self.array.get_duck_array())
File "D:\pyenv\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py", line 664, in get_duck_array
    return self.array.get_duck_array()
File "D:\pyenv\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py", line 551, in get_duck_array
    array = self.array[self.key]
File "D:\pyenv\lib\site-packages\rioxarray\_io.py", line 453, in __getitem__
    return indexing.explicit_indexing_adapter(
File "D:\pyenv\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py", line 858, in explicit_indexing_adapter
    result = raw_indexing_method(raw_key.tuple)
File "D:\pyenv\lib\site-packages\rioxarray\_io.py", line 428, in _getitem
    self.manager.acquire(needs_lock=False), self.vrt_params
File "D:\pyenv\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\file_manager.py", line 193, in acquire
    file, _ = self._acquire_with_cache_info(needs_lock)
File "D:\pyenv\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\file_manager.py", line 217, in _acquire_with_cache_info
    file = self._opener(*self._args, **kwargs)
File "D:\pyenv\lib\site-packages\rasterio\env.py", line 451, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwds)
File "D:\pyenv\lib\site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py", line 320, in open
    dataset = DatasetReader(path, driver=driver, sharing=sharing, **kwargs)
File "rasterio\_base.pyx", line 312, in rasterio._base.DatasetBase.__init__
```